# Intent 'Cannot resolve constructor' when trying to transfer double

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, navigation, double

I'm trying to use location data I get in one activity for a calculation in another and to transfer data I am trying to use an Intent. However, when I try to add the Intent, I keep getting the error

> 'Cannot resolve constructor'

The activity I'm trying to pass data from looks like this:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class CurrentLocationListener implements LocationListener {

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    if(location != null)
    {
        Double currentLat = location.getLatitude(); 
        Double currentLong = location.getLongitude(); 
        Log.e("Latitude :", "" + location.getLatitude());
        Log.e("Longitude :", "" + location.getLongitude());

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Lat", currentLat);
        intent.putExtra("Long", currentLong);
        CurrentLocationListener.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
 }
```

And this is where I'm trying to use the data in the other activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

parseButton.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View inputButtonView)
                        {
                            String latInputString = latFind.getText().toString();
                            String longInputString = longFind.getText().toString();
                            double latInputDouble = Double.parseDouble(latInputString);
                            double longInputDouble = Double.parseDouble(longInputString);

                            double dLon = (longInputDouble-currentLong);
                            double y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(latInputDouble);
                            double x = Math.cos(currentLat)
                                    *Math.sin(latInputDouble) - Math.sin(currentLat)
                                    *Math.cos(latInputDouble)*Math.cos(dLon);
                            double targetBearing = Math.toDegrees((Math.atan2(y, x)));
                            targetBearing = (360 - ((targetBearing + 360) % 360));
                        }
                });
```

So what I'm asking is this: **how can I properly transfer my Double data for Latitude and Longitude from one activity to the other?**

Comment: I'm also racking my brain as to how to properly call back that bundled data

Answer (score 0):

This is because you will need to pass **Application or activity** as a first parameter to the Intent Constructor.

Your **CurrentLocationListener** does not extend Activity class.It is not an Activity.So you can not pass 'this' in  intent constructor

Comment: Is there maybe some other way to pass the currentLat and currentLong variables from one activity to the other?

Comment: Where and how you are calling CurrentLocationListener?

Comment: I was trying to use it to store the users current location and then use that data in a calculation in the mainActivity. But I just now realized I can get them in the same activity without needing this one. Then I just have to figure out how to use them from there